# VSTS extensions Grid Control header style

Tags: javascript, tfs, azure-devops, visual-studio-extensions

Making my own VSTS extension. The extension returns a grid with the list of bugs in the project and some calculations made on these bugs.

I want to style the header of the grid to make the font bigger and with different background.

I checked the documentation from MS (https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/reference/client/controls/grid) and they mention the possibility to specify HeaderCss class. So I did the following:
- I created a CSS class in my html header:

```
<head>
    <style>
    .mystyle {
        background-color: coral;
        color: white;
        font-size: 25px;
    }
    </style>
    <title>Weighted Defect Count Calculation</title>
    <script src="sdk/scripts/VSS.SDK.js"></script>
</head>
```

I added the class name inside the javascript, where the grid columns options are defined:

```
                         width: "100%",
                         height: "500px",
                         source: sourceArray,
                         columns: [
                             { text: "ID", index: 0, width: 100, HeaderCss: { mystyle } },
                             { text: "Title", index: 1, width: 200 },
                             { text: "State", index: 2, width: 100 },
                             { text: "Severity", index: 3, width: 200 },
                             { text: "Likelihood", index: 4, width: 200 },
                             { text: "Assigned To", index: 5, width: 300 },
                         ]
```

I get a 401 Unauthorized error when I run the extension. If I remove the HeaderCss thingy then it works perfectly.

- I tried "mystyle" (with double qoutes). I get syntax error
- I tried 'mystyle' (with single qoute). I get syntax error

Anyone can help?

Documentation from MS: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/reference/client/controls/grid

Tutorial I followed to make the extension is here: http://nocture.dk/2016/01/02/lets-make-a-visual-studio-team-services-extension/

Comment: Can you show your entire extension in one drive? Besides, you can also refer the Build-Inspector example extension https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-extension-samples/blob/master/build-inspector/src/inspector/associatedItemsGrid.ts.

Comment: Sure. The extension index.html file can be found here (https://1drv.ms/u/s!AkWmBwckPdKZgQcRdU__hqwtiQVw). This is the only file in the extension, the others are the standard ones (vss-extension.json and VSS.SDK).

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue. Also I don't think specify headerCss will cause 401 error. Do you change the version of extension before packaging? You can try to clear cookies of internet browser and check the result. You also can debug the code through Developer tool (F12). On the other hand, the value of HeaderCss is string instead of array or object, so it should be like `HeaderCss: "mystyle"`.

Comment: What're scopes of your extension? (in vss-extension.json file)

Comment: The scope is vso.work

Comment: Using `headerCss:"mystyle"` instead. (First character is lowercase), I post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `headerCss:"mystyle"` instead. (First character is lowercase).

On the other hand, the value of `headerCss` is string instead of array or object.

Comment: Thanks. It works now. So actually MS documentation is wrong as it specifies headerCss: {string} instead of headerCss: "string"